# How to set Value of One field of Django model equal to Other field of other Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Hi i am Setting the value of one field of my Django model equal to value of other field of Other model. This value should change dynamically.

This is my first model

```
class MainModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='Email Address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True)
    payment_online = models.ForeignKey(OnlinePayments, null=True, blank=True)
    register_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    purchase_date = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='')
    is_csr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is second model

```
class OnlinePayments(models.Model):

    payer_email = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    payer_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payer_email
```

i want to set the value of purchase_date in MainModel equal to value of timestamp in OnlinePayments.

Any help would be appericiated

Answer (score 7):

You don't actually need to maintain two fields with the same value.

I'd define a method on `MainModel` and get the `timestamp` from the related model:

```
class MainModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='Email Address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True)
    payment_online = models.ForeignKey(OnlinePayments, null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    def get_purchase_date(self):
        return self.payment_online.timestamp if self.payment_online else None
```

Comment: Can you please guide how to call this method to set purchase_date

Comment: @user3408904 it should be set on `OnlinePayments` model. `get_purchase_date()` is just a view on the `timestamp` field value on the related model.

Comment: @user3408904 think about it. `purchase_date` makes sense for the payment, not for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I think @alecxe provided a great answer.
However, if you really want to store the information in 2 places you can override the save method on the `OnlinePayments` model so that whenever a record is saved on that model, you can manually save the `timestamp` value to `purchase_date` in `MainModel`.

Add the following save method to your `OnlinePayments` model (filling in the `purchase_date` assignment under the comment)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # save the value of self.timestamp into purchase_date

    super(OnlinePayments, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```